# ¿Cómo agregar un estilo al recorrer un texto externo?

Tags: css, reactjs

Buenas tardes :) tengo un dilema, en React estoy creando un blog y mi pregunta es si es posible agregar un estilo a un texto al cual estoy llamando de mi DB

Por ejemplo, puedo agregarle un espacio cada que lea "\n" en el texto y asi separo los parrafos.

```
const text =
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. \n when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.';

{text.split('\n\n').map(paragraph => (
                        <Typography
                            mt={2}
                            fontSize='1.125rem'
                            component='p'
                            color='text.secondary'
                            style={{
                                wordWrap: 'break-word',
                                hyphens: 'auto',
                            }}
                        >
                            {paragraph
                                .split('\n')
                                .reduce((total, line) => [
                                    total,
                                    <br />,
                                    <br />,
                                    line,
                                ])}
                        </Typography>
                    ))}
```

Con el código anterior puedo crear los párrafos de mi texto, pero aquí mi pregunta:
Cada que detecte un `<span>texto</span>` que le pueda agregar un estilo al span para que resalte del texto.
O al menos como puedo darle un estilo a un texto lineal recibido de una base de datos?
he estado investigando pero esta es mi ultima alternativa, agradecería mucho que me ayudaran. ;)